# Get an error when i try to open application from Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
    if "open" in text:
        app = text.split(" ", 1)
        self.respond("opening " + app[1])
        os.system("open -a " + app[1]  + ".app")
```

get this error

```
open: invalid option -- 'a'
Usage: open [OPTIONS] -- command

This utility help you to start a program on a new virtual terminal 
(VT).

Options:
-c, --console=NUM   use the given VT number;
-e, --exec          execute the command, without forking;
-f, --force         force opening a VT without checking;
-l, --login         make the command a login shell;
-u, --user          figure out the owner of the current VT;
-s, --switch        switch to the new VT;
-w, --wait          wait for command to complete;
-v, --verbose       print a message for each action;
-V, --version       print program version and exit;
-h, --help          output a brief help message.
```

Comment: The `open` command doesn't have an option `-a` so you can't use it. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: i just want to open a program which one i speak  for example if i said open firefox then firefox opened

Comment: What’s the difference to calling it directly with e.g. `os.system("firefox")`?

Comment: wow its working

Comment: Oh dear, still people using os.system(). Please note that it is horribly old fashioned and deprecated.

Comment: yes but its also important that the first letter is not capital when you call any program. eg: if you call "Firefox" you get error but "firefox" is working well

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need any additional command, just call the program directly:

```
os.system(app[1])
```

However, I’d rather use [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) for that.

Comment: See comment on question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm What do you recommend, [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/)?

Comment: subprocess, either .call or .Popen, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I call it directly:

```
os.system("firefox")
```

However, it's also important that the first letter is not capital when you call any program, i.e: if you call `Firefox` you get error but `firefox` is working well.